# What is the name of this science fiction story?

Tags: story-identification, audio-book, space-colonization

I am trying to identify the name and if possible a link to a story that I heard on librivox.org (maybe, I am not 100% sure).

At some point point in the future, human race has spread all over the galaxy, and each planet has its own religion and rules. There is a government organisation on earth that is trying to track down an individual who goes by the name of Thomas Paine who is an anarchist spreading revolution on all of the other planets. The hero is hired by this organization to track down TP, and is assigned a female assistant who will help him track down this Thomas Paine. I don't want to spoil the twist in the story here, but is someone aware of this story? If yes, then I'd very much like the name of the story. I am 99% sure I found this story on iTunes published by librivox, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: Was it a novel or a short story?

Comment: It was a novellete I believe. It was an audiobook story in 5 parts (each part 10-15 min long).

Comment: This sounds familiar, but I can't remember anything about it :(

Comment: I BELIEVE this is a Roger Zelazny novel, but I can't find it.. Perhaps the name will help ya, tho :)

Comment: Do you see it [here](http://wiki.librivox.org/index.php/LibriVox_Short_Science_Fiction_Index)?

Comment: Could it be "To Save The Sun" by Ben Bova?  I read that a few years ago.  I can't remember if there was a character named Thomas Paine, but the setting was similar in that humans were spread out across the galaxy and there was a lot of political intrigue going on and some planets were trying to separate from the main human government and form their own governments.

Comment: Can you put the twist in a spoiler? It might help narrow down the search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that's the novella "[Ultima Thule](http://www.loyalbooks.com/book/Ultima-Thule)" by Mack Reynolds, part of his "United Planets" series.

> Ronny Bronston has dreamed all his life of getting a United Planets job that would take him off-world. He finally gets the opportunity when he is given a provisional assignment with Bureau of Investigation, Section G. But will he be able to complete his assignment and find the elusive Tommy Paine?

The link above is to the audiobook version, which would fit with you remembering this as being a Librivox recording.

Comment: Oh my god! This is it! It only took 4 years, but I have the answer, thanks to you! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Is it by chance "Tom Paine Maru" by L. Neil Smith? It seems to fit your description nearly to a tee.

http://www.phoenixpick.com/ex/TPM-50.pdf